# Can I store Apple's public key for verifying token signature?

Tags: ios, oauth, public-key-encryption, apple-sign-in, sign-in-with-apple

In order to implement OAuth with Apple, we make a call `GET https://appleid.apple.com/auth/keys`.

(According to the documentation in https://docs.developer.pv.apple.com/documentation/signinwithapplerestapi/fetch_apple_s_public_key_for_verifying_token_signature)

The result goes along the lines of:

```
{
    "kty": "RSA",
    "kid": "1234567890",
    "use": "...",
    "alg": "RS256",
    "n": "...",
    "e": "..."
}
```

Can I trust that this information will not change without notice? Or should I make this request every time we need to use Apple's public key?

Comment: you should cache the key with "kid" for subsequent uses, and fetch new key again when you see JWT is signed with different "kid".

Answer (score 0):

It can change, but not that often.
So you can cache it, and verify it with the cached ones.
And then when you see a token coming in that can't be verified with the cached key, then update your cached keys and try verifying the token, again.